# Reputation across the sites

Tags: support, reputation

I've got a question about *statistic* and it needs some pictures.
In the stats.stackexchange my reputation (1) do not allow to post pictures ((
Here my rep is 18. Is it possible to merge reputations with all accounts?

Comment: But you can put the picture elsewhere and post a link. I think even with 1 reputation you are allowed to include 1-2 links in a post.

Comment: and some kind person with more reputation might edit your post so that the image is visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - it's not possible, with one exception: once you have a certain amount of reputation on one of the sites (200 maybe?) you will automatically get 100 rep on others.

Comment: One exception? Who's that?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: A user called "Community"

Comment: @Tim, no, I think mixedmath's edit has clarified the situation.

Comment: 200 is the correct value: From Meta.SO questions
[How do reputation bonuses for associations between accounts work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/how-do-reputation-bonuses-for-associations-between-accounts-work) and
[How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work): *you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)*